# jcaptcha integration with struts

Tags: struts, captcha

I'm trying to interate a struts 1.3.8 app with jcaptcha-1.0; I added the jcaptcha jar to the app lib and added

```
<%@ taglib uri="jcaptcha" prefix="jcaptcha"%>
```

to my form

The app couldn't find the file, so I added the following to the web.xml file

```
<taglib-uri>jcaptcha</taglib-uri>
<taglib-location>/WEB-INF/lib/jcaptcha-1.0-all.jar</taglib-location>
</taglib>
```

And now I get the null pointer exception:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to read TLD "META-INF/taglib.tld" from JAR file
```

Any clues ? Recommendations about otther captchas that work with struts are welcomed.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `<%@ taglib uri="http://jcaptcha.sourceforge.net" prefix="jcaptcha" %>`

If that fails, try `<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/jcaptcha.tld" prefix="jcaptcha"%>` and create the `jcaptcha.tld` file in `WEB-INF` with this content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<!--
  ~ JCaptcha, the open source java framework for captcha definition and integration
  ~ Copyright (c)  2007 jcaptcha.net. All Rights Reserved.
  ~ See the LICENSE.txt file distributed with this package.
  -->

<!DOCTYPE taglib PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems,
 Inc.//DTD JSP Tag Library 1.1//EN" "http://java.sun.com/j2ee/dtds/web-jsptaglibrary_1_1.dtd">

<taglib>
    <tlibversion>1.0</tlibversion>
    <jspversion>1.1</jspversion>
    <shortname>jcaptcha-struts-taglib</shortname>
    <uri>http://jcaptcha.sourceforge.net</uri>
    <info>JCAPTCHA Taglib for the base module</info>

    <tag>
        <name>question</name>
        <tagclass>com.octo.captcha.module.struts.taglib.QuestionTag</tagclass>
        <bodycontent>empty</bodycontent>
        <info>Display the jcaptcha question for this session</info>
    </tag>
    <tag>
        <name>message</name>
        <tagclass>com.octo.captcha.module.taglib.MessageTag</tagclass>
        <bodycontent>empty</bodycontent>
        <info>Display the jcaptcha failure message for this session</info>
    </tag>
</taglib>
```